# static web method - the risk of shared values between users

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, static, webforms

this question is about using static modifier within an asp.net webforms application 
i am a begginer, and although i have never encountered problems with this static "issue"
i still am little worried about that issue and would like to clear this out .

lately i have started using `Ajax/jQuery` POST instead of `asp.net` 'normal' postback

so i could take advantage of javascript objects and also avoid page refresh when interacting with server

my question is regarding the ajax post . it is using a **Static method** 
returning information to users

some background info about the client side code...(you can skip to Server side below if u like)

client side :

HTML

```
 <td id="TD_Actions_<%=RecordIdSlot%>" class="RepTblDataTds ">
    <!-- will be used to trigger jquery function instead of asp imageButton that causes a postback
    <span id="SpanEditRecord"> 
       <img src="img/EditPic.png" style="width:20px;" class="CssClassImgBut_Edit" />
    </span>
</td>
```

jquery :

```
var SpanEditRecord = $('#SpanEditRecord'); // the trigger span
// onclick event post data to code behind
SpanEditRecord.click(function () {

    var Recid = $(this).parent().attr('id').split('_')[2];// takes the Sql table RecordiD
    var data = [];
    data.push({ key: 'RecordId', value: parseInt(Recid) }); //usually there's more data in "data"

    var targetUrl = "default.aspx/EditKkRecord";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: targetUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify({ SentPars: data }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (response) { 
                      getResponseFromEditRequest(response.d);
         },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);

        }
    });


});

 //handle callback /response from C# server side code
function getResponseFromEditRequest(htmlret) {
     var packagerec = htmlret.split(',');
       ........ 
        ........
}
```

and now to the topic in question ..

**C# Server Side**

this part is the issue in question, 
is that `[WebMethod]` is unsafe, when using it and several users ? 
could it be accidently sharing the same return value because it is a static method ?

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string EditKkRecord(object SentPars)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> NwDataDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            string tmpSQLstr = "";
            try
            {

                Array aa = (Array)SentPars;


                foreach (Dictionary<string, object> pair in aa)
                {
                    NwDataDict.Add((string)pair["key"], pair["value"].ToString());
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }

            if (NwDataDict.Count > 0)
               return EditRecordFromtblKupaKtanaDb(NwDataDict);
            return tmpSQLstr;
      }

    static string EditRecordFromtblKupaKtanaDb(Dictionary<string, string> todayKupa)
    {
       interact with database;
       return "comaSeparated - columns values as a string";
     }
```

so could it happen in this scenario that user a, b, and c, will trigger that web method and share the same return value if say they all try and edit the same "RecordId"

or even worse (i could think), if they all editing different records and actually the action could be shared from the first user... same record ..

when is it actually unsafe to use `static` and is it unsafe in this code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is safe to run your method as a static, as long as it does not depend on static variables that are outside of your static method.

Here a example of how not to use statics in asp.net web applications:

```
    public static string SaveSomething;
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        SaveSomething = "something";
        //... do more code
        AnotherAction(SaveSomething);
    }
```

First the SaveSomething string property is set to your value. In the meanwhile this property could be set by another request/user because it shares the property. Now if you recall the property and use it for AnotherAction it may not be the same value as you initially set. If you want to use references to external static variables, you have to be sure those variables are safe to use in that manner. Most of the cases they are read only.

However it is possible to lock the property with the lock statement:

```
    public static string SaveSomething;
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        lock (SaveSomething)
        {
             SaveSomething = "something";
             //... do more code
             AnotherAction(SaveSomething);
        }
    }
```

[The lock keyword marks a statement block as a critical section by obtaining the mutual-exclusion lock for a given object, executing a statement, and then releasing the lock.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: could you give an example to how would it be safe to use it with global variables ? like how to pass it some other values of program to return or if its difficult to think it, could you supply a sample code for wrong usage variables that are out of the webmethod scope give an example  vs correct usage (correct being not shared)